# EPiServer Home page not loading "Incorrect link"

Tags: .net, webforms, episerver, episerver-7

We are seeing a very strange sudden error on one of our production sites. Suddenly the home page is not displaying. We're seeing the standard EPiServer "Incorrect link" message.

Oddly we can see the page in the CMS fine although clicking view on site gives the same above error. The site also works on all other languages except it's master language. You can also access other pages on the master language site.

In the log file I can see:
EPiServer.Web.TemplateResolver: Home: Selected ~/Templates/Pages/Home.aspx. (tag='', channel='', category='Page')

Which is the correct template but it's followed by:

EPiServer.Web.Routing.Segments.PartialSegment: Could not load content with id '61'

61 is the correct ID.

I can't figure out what could have happened to cause this suddenly.

The site is built using web forms on EPiServer 7.5.

Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Daniel

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem this morning. The home page had incorrect configuration on the Fallback Languages. The client had changed this without our knowledge which was the cause of the page not displaying.

The Fallback Language was set to a language that the site did not exist in. Once we changed this over the site began to work again.